# Unable to assign a random value from an array (error: cannot find symbol)

Tags: java, arrays

Hey I am creating a simple card game and I am unable to fix a problem I have encountered. I have created a method DC to return a random int value from a cards array, but I keep getting this error.

```
TwentyOne.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
                a = new Random().nextInt(cards.length);
                        ^
  symbol:   class Random
  location: class TwentyOne
```

This is my DC method.

```
public static int DC(int card){
    //fields
        int cards[];
        int a;
        cards = new int[30];
        //Populate card array with random values
        for (int i=0; i < cards.length; i++){
            cards[i] = (int)(Math.random()*13)+1;
        }
        //select a random value from cards array
        a = new Random().nextInt(cards.length);
        return a;
```

In case its required, here is my main class (have not gotten far  in coding it).

```
public class TwentyOne{



    public static void main(String[] args){
        //fields

        int DealerHand[];
        int PlayerHand[];
        int CardCount[];
    //Create Arrays
        DealerHand = new int[16];
        PlayerHand = new int[16];
        CardCount = new int[0];
    //Let the games begin   
        System.out.println("Twenty-One Game starts!");
        PlayerHand[1] = DC(1);
        PlayerHand[2] = DC(1);

        System.out.println("Players Hand: "+ PlayerHand[0] + PlayerHand[1]);
     }
```

Would appreciate any help anyone could give me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you import `Random`?

Comment: import java.util.Random

Comment: That was the problem, thanks guys.

Comment: According to the error , java.util.Random should fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code.

First, be sure to import `java.util.Random` at the top of the file:

```
import java.util.Random;
```

Secondly, you should not create a new `Random` instance every time `DC` is called. Create the `Random` instance as a class-level variable:

```
private Random r = new Random();
public static int DC(int card){
    //fields
    int cards[];
    int a;
    cards = new int[30];
    //Populate card array with random values
    for (int i=0; i < cards.length; i++){
        cards[i] = (int)(Math.random()*13)+1;
    }
    //select a random value from cards array
    a = r.nextInt(cards.length);
    return a;
}
```

Also, I see that your `DC` method has a `card` parameter, but you didn't make use of this parameter anywhere in the method. You can just delete that, ya know.

Comment: as another side node, using a proper `IDE` will help you to fix issues like this easily, as they promote solutions to problems, like missing imports.